# Multiple object references

Tags: c#, .net, object

This question is about object references..

Below is my helper class..

```
class helperv2
{
    Workbook mainworkbook;
    //fill column names method
    public void FillColumnnames(DatabaseAdapter db,Workbook workbook)
    {
        //do some random stuff 

        //at the end of method
        mainworkbook = workbook;
    }
    public Workbook filldata(string sql)
    {
        //do some work on mainworkbook instance and return mainworkbook

        return mainworkbook;
    }
}
```

Now I am using above helper class in one of my methods as below

```
public string buildworkbook(Workbook workbook)
{
    helperv2 hlp=new helperv2();
    hlp.fillcolumnames(db,workbook);
    workbook=hlp.filldata(string sql);
}
```

Now my question is how these multiple object references are kept track off in below flow ..

1. Buildworkbook gets a empty workbook instance passed
2. Now fill column names, fills all the columns to the workbook and at
   the end it points to the mainworkbook instance.
3. Now fill data works on the mainworkbook instance and fills the data and
   it returns a workbook..

As you can see I am again assigning that to a workbook instance and returning it

This works, but I am not able to understand how these multiple references work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All variables for objects in .NET are *references*. That means that all variables for classes are just links to the actual objects. A variable do not contain it.

So if you do this:

```
Workbook book;
```

You do not get an actual object. You can try it yourself by trying to modify it:

```
Workbook book;
book.Title = "Hello"; //will throw NullReferenceException.
```

You create new objects by calling `new`:

```
//this code will create four new workbooks.
new Workbook();
new Workbook();
new Workbook();
new Workbook();
```

But since you do not store a reference in a variable, the garbage collector will delete those objects, as all *unreferenced* objects will be collected.

So when you do this:

```
var book = new Workbook();
var book2 = book;
```

You simply state that `book2` should point at the same object as `book`. No new object is created.

Same goes for return values:

```
public Workbook DoSomething(Workbook book)
{
   book.Title = "Hello";
   return book;
}

var book = new Workbook();
var book2 = DoSomething(book);
```

`book2` and `book` will still point at the same object as all class variables contains references to the actual objects.

As variables are references, you do not have to use a return value. To change the original object this is enough:

```
public void DoSomething(Workbook book)
{
   book.Title = "Hello";
}

var book = new Workbook();
DoSomething(book);
// 'book' now got a new title.
```

Now back to your code. The way you have designed your util class, no one will understand how it works. When will the main wookbook be returned? When will the workbook passed as an argument be returned? Either make all methods take a workbook as an argument or pass the workbook as an constructor argument. If you want to have a main workbook, create a method or property which can be used to assign it. Something like `helper.AssignMainWoorkbook(workbook);`.

My suggestion is that you simply do not use a return value as the passed workbook will be the one which is modified by the methods.

Comment: Most of this answer seems workable, but the first sentence is wrong. "pass by reference" is a reasonably well defined concept, it's [defined in C#](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/0f66670z.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396), and it's *not* true that anything is passed by reference, by default. It's just unfortunate that there are two similar sounding concepts in C# ("references" and "pass by reference") and by using the wrong terminology, you're more likely to confuse or force unlearning to have to happen later.

Comment: Very true. Changed the wording to remove ambiguity. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I will assume WorkBook is a class.

- In case of class, each time you declare a variable of class like  `Workbook myworkbook;`, it is a declaration that variable `myworkbook` is of type `Workbook` and it would store a null reference as no memory is being allocated.
- `Workbook myworkbook = new Workbook();` this initialize the object and allocate the memory as per the class members declared in the Class declaration of  Workbook. Additional memory for Synchronization Block Index and Type object pointer is also allocated along with class members in the Heap.
- In case you try a declaration like below, then the variable `myworkbook2` would only contain the reference to the already created `myworkbook`. Hence, no additional memory is used. However, the variable myworkbook2 would be in Stack on memory.

  ```
   Workbook myworkbook = new Workbook();
   Workbook myworkbook2 = myworkbook;
  ```
- Passing Parameters across methods can be done in 2 ways. Passing by `reference` or by `value`. In .net, by default parameters are passed to methods by value. However, if you are passing a class, since the class is a reference type, the reference is passed. Hence, if you make any change to a property of a parameter the same changes are reflected at the calling function, which is happening in your case.

From [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0f66670z.aspx), Additional reading : [here](http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/parameters.html).

> A variable of a reference type does not contain its data directly; it
>   contains a reference to its data. When you pass a reference-type
>   parameter by value, it is possible to change the data pointed to by
>   the reference, such as the value of a class member. However, you
>   cannot change the value of the reference itself; that is, you cannot
>   use the same reference to allocate memory for a new class and have it
>   persist outside the block. To do that, pass the parameter using the
>   ref or out keyword. For simplicity, the following examples use ref.

Answer (score 1):

The bit that is keeping your reference going in your helper class is one little field you have set up. It's the `Workbook mainworkbook;`

At the end of your `FillColumnnames()` method, you assign that variable with the workbook passed to the method and that is now always set in the object of `helperv2 hlp=new helperv2();` Since you never create a new object of `hlp`, the reference inside to the `mainworkbook` will still be assigned to the workbook you passed in the method `FillColumnnames()`.

This means, that after you call the function of `fillData`, it returns the value stored in the parameter of `mainworkbook`in your `helperv2` class. If you want to examine it further, you could create a getter in your `helperv2`class and check it at each step of the process, something like:

```
public WorkBook getWorkbook(){
    return this.mainworkbook;
}
```

And then in your `buildworkbook` class you can call `hlp.getWorkbook();` to have a look at the object.